# Multiprocessing in Python - How to use all cores when running DBSCAN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiprocessing

I coded some code using DBSCAN, but when run predict function, program use only 1 CPU(100%) while other CPUs is free. Anyone can modify the below "dbscan_predict" function so it can use all 8 CPUs that my computer have???(CPU 4 cores 8 threads)

```
def dbscan_predict(dbscan_model, X_new, metric=np.linalg.norm):
# Result is noise by default
y_new = np.ones(shape=len(X_new), dtype=int)*(-1)

# Iterate all input samples for a label
for j, x_new in enumerate(X_new):
    # Find a core sample closer than EPS
    for i, x_core in enumerate(dbscan_model.components_): 
        if metric(x_new - x_core) < dbscan_model.eps:
            # Assign label of x_core to x_new
            y_new[j] = dbscan_model.labels_[dbscan_model.core_sample_indices_[i]]
            break

return y_new
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the multiprocessing package of python. You can define the function and split you dataframe inside the multiprocessing.pool() method. Then this will distribute the work on different cores.

You can check the number of cores using multiprocessing.cpu_count() as well and then take the decision on the basis of that.